# Split a document by its subdocuments

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am facing an issue right now, and can't get to find a solution to it.
I have a collection with subdocuments in an array in each document, and I would like to retrieve a document per subdocument.

With an example it would be simpler to explain. Let's say I have this "schema" for a collection :

```
{
    a: String,
    b: [String]
}
```

where both a and b are required.
A document of this collection would look like :

```
{
    a : 'hey',
    b: ['me', 'you']
}
```

I would like to find a way to make a mongoose query that wouldn't return this document as it is, but these two documents :

```
[{
    a: 'hey',
    b: 'me'
 },
 {
     a: 'hey',
     b: 'you'
 }]
```

Is that possible ?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. : I know that I can do this once I've retrieved the list with a simple JS function, but I can't wait to have retrieved the full list to begin to use it.

Comment: You can't do a projection like that on the database without using the aggregation framework (which doesn't seem like a good fit here), and even if you could, the results don't match the declared schema? You'd need to bypass mongoose, and build the results the way you want them.

Comment: @WiredPrairie Why don't you think the aggregation framework can't be a good fit ?
Also, I don't need the results to fit with the Schema, it was just to explain how the documents were formatted in the collection.

Comment: Why? Because it's limited in results (no more than 16MB), and becomes more difficult to manage as the schema of the docs evolves. You'll need to "project" fields, etc. It's designed to aggregate, sum, group, not expand.

Comment: Also, I consider this type of work, "busy-work" and best left to the client, rather than getting the most expensive aspect of most applications to do tasks like this. You're sending back more binary data than actually was stored in the DB.

Comment: @WiredPrairie There are very little chances that this data gets over this 16M limitation, but I understand this concern, and thanks for this heads up.
What are you considering the client ? The node server as a client of the mongo one, or the actual client loading the page ? Because in the second case, it's not possible to let this work on client-side, these results are used with a SEO objective, so need to be calculated before sending the page.

Comment: node server == client.

Comment: @WiredPrairie Then I don't agree since I'm expecting Mongo's code to be more optimized than mine for doing exactly the same thing. And if one server should be expanded to more servers, it is more likely going to be the mongo one than the node one.

Comment: You can choose to disagree. It's your app and your computing resources and money. Just remember what costs more to support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what the [`$unwind`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) aggregation operator does:

```
MyModel.aggregate({$unwind: '$b'}, function(err, result) { ... });
```

`results` gets an array that looks like:

```
[ { _id: 524d5f6e1576f8a0f35fca8e, a: 'hey', b: 'me' },
  { _id: 524d5f6e1576f8a0f35fca8e, a: 'hey', b: 'you' } ]
```